# React-Native Could not get batchedBridge Error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am a beginner in React Native (version 0.40.0) and I have encountered a problem while developing a project. When I run `npm start` (npm version-4.6.0) I get no errors and the packager starts normally. Running `react-native run-android` also doesn't give any errors however when the app starts in the Android Emulator( Nexus 6 API 23 ) I see the "Unfortunately app had to be closed" notice. The logcats in Android Studio are:

```
07-22 04:56:15.504 5325-5353/com.downtofood E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
                                                          Process: com.downtofood, PID: 5325
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:24)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:158)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:431)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$400(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:51)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:447)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:33)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                           Caused by: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                           Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please let me know what I can do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to quote a solution form [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9336#issue-170410966) issue on the official react-native github repository.

```
react-native run-android
react-native start --reset-cache
```

To better understand how this works and to look for another solution there are several issues under similar name/tags on the issue page of the repository itself.